# Show that are logically equivalent

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Can you answer me , please.

1- Show that (p→r)∧(q→r) and (p∨q)→r are logically equivalent

2- show that (p → r) ∨ (q → r) and (p ∧ q) → r are logically equivalent

without truth table .

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange community. It would be better if you tell us the effort you have made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

1.

Note that the implication rule: $p\to q\equiv \neg p\vee q$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(p\to r)\wedge(q\to r) & \equiv (\neg p\vee r)\wedge (\neg q\vee r)\quad \text{by implication rule}\\
 & \equiv (\neg p\wedge \neg q)\vee r \quad\text{by distributive rule}\\
& \equiv \neg (p\vee  q)\vee r \quad\text{by De Morgan's rule}\\
& \equiv (p\vee  q)\to r \quad\text{by Implication rule}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
2. 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(p\to r)\vee(q\to r) & \equiv (\neg p\vee r)\vee (\neg q\vee r)\quad \text{by implication rule}\\
 & \equiv (\neg p\vee \neg q)\vee r \quad\text{by associative and commutative rule}\\
& \equiv \neg (p\wedge  q)\vee r \quad\text{by De Morgan's rule}\\
& \equiv (p\wedge  q)\to r \quad\text{by Implication rule}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

---

I hope this answer your question.